# Which type of algorithm is used in this

Tags: .net

```
public class SecurityModule1
{
    public string CreateHash(string strSource)
    {
        byte[] bytHash;
        UnicodeEncoding uEncode = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] bytSource = uEncode.GetBytes(strSource);
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        bytHash = sha1.ComputeHash(bytSource);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytHash);
    }
}
```

can you explain me which algorithm is used in this security module and explain about that algorithm

Comment: SHA1? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Comment: This is a Method that encodes a string into a SHA1 format...

Comment: It does three things. Encodes the string as unicode, computes its SHA1 hash, and returns the base 64 representation of the SHA1 hash.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search in Google, by SHA1CryptoServiceProvider, will give you the answer. Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Computes the SHA1 hash value for the input data using the implementation provided by the cryptographic service provider (CSP).

About SHA1 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

> SHA-1 produces a 160-bit (20-byte) hash value. A SHA-1 hash value is typically rendered as a hexadecimal number, 40 digits long.
>
> SHA stands for "secure hash algorithm". The four SHA algorithms are structured differently and are named SHA-0, SHA-1, SHA-2, and SHA-3. SHA-0 is the original version of the 160-bit hash function published in 1993 under the name "SHA": it was not adopted by many applications. Published in 1995, SHA-1 is very similar to SHA-0, but alters the original SHA hash specification to correct alleged weaknesses. SHA-2, published in 2001, is significantly different from the SHA-1 hash function.
>
> In 2005, cryptanalysts found attacks on SHA-1 suggesting that the algorithm might not be secure enough for ongoing use.

And it keeps on and on...